# R 4.2.0: summary() won't work with keras models

Tags: r, keras

I've just upgraded R to the latest version 4.2.0 and also updated all my packages as well. Everything works fine with one exception: mymodel |> summary()

```
"Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
TypeError: summary() got an unexpected keyword argument 'show_trainable'"
```

mymodel is any keras model (like LSTM or CNN) created with functional API.

Within my conda environment I use tensorflow 2.6.0 and even there all python packages are up to date.

Do you know the reason for this error message?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when using `summary(my model)`?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem

Comment: This is fixed in the development version of the R package.